# base class function called even after virtual used

Tags: c++, polymorphism

[Running code link](http://ideone.com/xc9yft) 
I have a base class of object IObject from which 2 derived classes derivedObject and derivedObject2 are created . I have an IAlgoInterace base implementation of print which takes IObject  and then i derived derivedAlgo  from IAlgoInterace  from the same . The derived class derivedAlgo   overrides the print method with arguments of derived class derivedObject  & derivedObject 2 . When i use print function to print object it is going to base class .

Why is my derived class's right print called?
What can be done to not change base IAlgoInterace and still achieve this functionality

Aim: Implementing strategy design pattern and code pasted here is a small executable part of same. My aim is that the base class IAlgoInterace will never be needed to provide more information than that it has a print which can take all different kinds of derived class objects . Actual implementation ie in derived algo   will be based on derived object thats passed in it . print in derived algo will use data elements from the right object being passed in it .

So    derivedAlgo class will print derivedObject2 differently from say derivedAlgo2 class

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

class IObject
{
public:
     int data;
};

class derivedObject: public IObject
{
public:
    int dataAdditonal;
};
class derivedObject2: public IObject
{
public:
    int dataAdditonal;
};


class IAlgoInterace
{

public:
    virtual void print(IObject * object)
    {
        cout << "\n base algo called";
    }
};

class derivedAlgo :  public IAlgoInterace
{
    public:
    virtual void print(derivedObject * object)
    {
        cout << "\n derived called for objct type 1 " ;
    }
    virtual void print(derivedObject2 * object)
    {
        cout << "\n derived called for object type 2  " ;
    }
};

class derivedAlgo2 :  public IAlgoInterace
{
    public:
    virtual void print(derivedObject * object)
    {
        cout << "\n derived algo2  called for objct type 1 " ;
    }
    virtual void print(derivedObject2 * object)
    {
        cout << "\n derived algo2  called for object type 2  " ;
    }
};
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    IObject * object = new derivedObject();
    IObject * object2 = new derivedObject2();
    IAlgoInterace * algo = new derivedAlgo();

    algo->print(object);
    algo->print(object2);
    int y ;
    cin >> y;
}
```

Comment: *"The derived class `derivedAlgo` overrides the `print` method"* False. `virtual void print(derivedObject * object)` does not override `virtual void print(IObject * object)`. It's an overload; the two methods are independent and unrelated. To override, you need to actually match the signature of the base class' method (modulo covariant return types).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik so i would need to modify my base class to override all such derived dataObject  types ?

Comment: What you need to do rather depends on the goal you are trying to achieve. That was never adequately explained.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik i have tried to explain by editing question . was i able to express ?

Comment: Add the `override` specifier to your functions and witness it not compiling.

Comment: Well, if `IAlgoInterace` needs to know how to print all kinds of objects, then it needs a `print` overload for each kind of object.

Comment: problem with overloading is that base IAlgoInterace class will now contain all possible functions which could be from derivedAlgo or derivedAlgo2 .  which seeme to be wrong design . How does strategy pattern algorithms acess object  data . Does what you suggest is the only option ?

Comment: You could give the `IObject` a mandatory function which returns a string to be printed and then call that in the `IAlgoInter(f)ace` function, retrieving the string and adding any other before printing it. That way `IAlgoInterace` need not know about subclasses of `IObject`. Example [here](http://ideone.com/aYNhiG). I'm not sure exactly the output you are looking for, but it could probably be adapted from this example.